# Assigning pointer to a different address in function

Tags: c++

just curious what is the explanation of this?

```
void f(int * x);

int test = 100;


int main()
{
 int z = 35;
 int * a = &z;
 f(a);
 cout<<*a;
..
}


void f(int *x)
{
    x = &test;
}
```

We are taught we can use pointers inside function arguments if we want to modify the "outside" object (as `a` in this case). But `x = &test` does not do much, and the `cout` still prints 35.
I know `*x =someVal` would work though in f().

Comment: In C++, you'd use references. Plus, note that in your function you're modifying the pointer itself (which is passed by value, that's why it doesn't change), not what it points to.

Comment: You're changing a copy of a pointer not a pointer itself

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: Of course, x is now a local variable and modifying it has no effect outside of the local scope. It does seem pointless :-)

Comment: Yep, to sum up: I also had the doubt that essentially I am changing copy of a pointer!

Comment: If you're "taught to use pointers", it's time to change teachers.

Comment: @KerrekSB generally lectures cover all the language elements while learning.... pointers are part of cpp, so why shouldn't they teach?

Comment: @pinkpanther probably because changing something's value inside a function is not something that is worth doing with pointers, when you can do it with references (unless you work for google).

Comment: @juanchopanza: is google anti-ref too? I thought they just avoid exceptions

Comment: @BalogPal last time I looked, they were anti non-const references.

Comment: ah, I start to vaguely recalling thet part too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C pointers are passed by value just like ints, floats, etc. So if you want to modify it and have that modification be visible outside of the function call, you need to pass a pointer to the thing you want to modify, in this case that's a pointer to a int pointer:

```
void f(int **x) {
    *x = &test;
}
```

However, in C++ passing a reference is a much better approach:

```
void f(int*& x) {
    x = &test;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you labeled the question C, what you taught it would be acceptable. For C++ it is techically correct but morally wrong, you should pass by reference to modify the object, not fiddling with pointer and address.

In your code you get what you coded for: pass a pointer and then reassign that poitner's value. That is not visible outside the function. What you intended to do is

```
void f(int *x)
{
    *x = 42;
}
```

and the C++ version would be like:

```
void f(int &x)
{
  x = 42;
}

int main()
{
  int z = 35;
  f(z);
  cout << z;
}
```

Comment: I didn't ask how to modify the outer value. I just asked for explanation, which seems to be that I was modifying actually a copy to the pointer.

Comment: Indeed, as H2CO3 pointed out you didn't ask a proper question, please next time do.

Comment: I thought it was clear :) Because I asked for "explanation of this".

Comment: @user2054339 so is your problem solved? did you get the concept?

Comment: @pinkpanther: Yes, if the answer is that I basically modified copy of the pointer, then yes.

Comment: @user2054339 you have modified what local variable of f 'x' points to from `&a` to `&start` and that has nothing to do with `&a`. Only if you dereference the pointer `x` with `*` that has any thing to do with whatever it points to...

Comment: Yes, pinkpanther, the thing is the function argument int *x is basically a copy of `a` -- the only thing these two have common, is where they _point_ to.

Comment: @user2054339 well, accept one of the answers so that it helps future visitors....

Comment: @pinkpanther: well the answers I like are provided, in comments, how do I accept them?

Comment: @user2054339 well, write up your own answer taking the ideas from comments and else where then post it....and accept it...) or ofcourse you can wait for new answers.... good night:)

Comment: yeah, looks like a good idea, and gains some self-teaching badge too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Due to recommendation of one of the members I am adding my own answer which I derived from the other peoples responses. So thanks go to them. 
Basically the problem in my code was that **I was changing a copy of my pointer.**

The only thing `x` in function f and the value `a` passed to f have in common is *the address where they point to*.